# Apache server causes tar.gz files to download as uncompressed tarballs still named .gz

Tags: apache-2.2, gzip, tar

We are hosting a number of .tar.gz files on our Apache server.  When we download these files, the filename of the downloaded file is the same as on the server... something.tar.gz... but the file is actually an uncompressed tarball (as if just a .tar).

The response headers include

```
Content-Type: application/x-gzip
Content-Encoding: x-gzip
```

What Apache configuration can be used to cause these files to be downloaded as gzipped tarballs still named .tar.gz?

Answer (score 3):

I had to add the following directive to get intentionally gzipped files to download without silently decompressing:

```
AddEncoding x-identity .tar.gz .gz .tgz
```

Answer (score 0):

The problematic configuration was having both

```
AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
```

and

```
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
```

Removing the `AddEncoding` line fixed the problem.